# Connection between two networks with different IPs and identical subnets?

Tags: routing, ipv4, subnet, network, gateway

How can we establish communication between two networks with different IPs but same Subnets?

```
Network Connection 1: (Factory Network for machinery)
I.P = 192.168.19.X
S.N = 255.255.255.0
G.W = 0.0.0.0

Network Connection 2: (Connected to Internet)
I.P = 10.32.24.X
S.N = 255.255.255.0
G.W = 10.32.21.1
```

So how does a user access devices in the Connection 1 network from Connection 2 network?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have 10.32.21.1 gateway on connection 2?  it should be 10.32.24.1  ( Plus use need gateway on Connection - 1

Comment: subnet says 'how many computers are allowed to use in your IP range'. You can not talk only about subnet without IP address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Connection between two networks with different IPs and identical
>   subnets?

That does not match the information in your question. Your two networks have completely separate subnets, but they use the same IP (IPv4).

Routers route packets between networks.

One problem you have is that the devices in Network 1 need to have a gateway configured, otherwise they cannot communicate outside the network. The gateway is a router and the host on the network that knows how to reach other networks. A host will determine if the destination of a packet is on a different network, and it will frame the packet with the LAN address of the gateway for a packet destined to a different network.

It looks like you just need to connect Network 1 to your router and configure that router interface to be in the same network, then configure the hosts on that network to use the address of the router interface as their gateway. The router should automatically route packets between the networks.

Comment: Hi Ron, Thanks for your response. So if I add a router to the Network 1 say for example with I.P = 192.168.19.250 and S.N = 255.255.255.0 and then assign the devices on network 1 to use G.W = 192.168.19.250. Will that ensure users to access Network 1 from network 2?

Comment: Either you use the existing router for both networks, or you will need to do more. If you add a separate router, you will somehow need to connect it to the existing router and create a new network for the link between and use a routing protocol or static routes, or you could also connect the new router to Network 2, but then the hosts on Network 2 would need to be configured with a specific static route to Network 1 through the new router. The easiest thing to do is connect both networks to the existing router because it will inherently know about both networks.

Answer (score 0):

In the network 1 must be configure a default gateway that have connection to internet and this gateway also must know the network 2.